# Gnome3 - Change window drag shortcut

Tags: gnome, shortcuts, window-manager

Gnome defaults to using Alt+LeftMouse dragging for moving windows around - I *hate* this feature and it breaks some apps I use.  In Gnome2 you could change the modifier key in one of the settings dialogs, but I can't find the corresponding one in Gnome3, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GNOME Shell window manager, Mutter, is based on Metacity (GNOME 2) <s>and uses the same settings. They are located in GConf at `/apps/metacity`.</s>

Use *gconf-editor* or *gconftool-2* to change the `/apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier` setting to your preferred modifier. For example, to choose the "Windows" key, I use:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier --type string "<Super>"
```

In recent GNOME versions, configuration is accessed through GSettings, with Linux using the `dconf` backend. To change the setting through GSettings (recommended), use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier "'<Super>'"
```

To write it directly to the dconf backend, use:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/mouse-button-modifier "'<Super>'"
```

You can also find it in GNOME Tweak Tool under *Windows → Modifier to use for window click actions*.

Changes should take effect immediately.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be set in **Tweak Tool**:

**Windows** > **Window Action Key** > select **Alt**

[image: Tweak Tool]